# I want each part to appear separately

Tags: html, css

The page has two parts. The first part I want in the right side,
It needs to have following characteristics:
`position: absolute;
left: 0`

https://4.top4top.net/p_1339kl3zo1.png

https://5.top4top.net/p_1339rvmaj2.png

https://6.top4top.net/p_1339lk6ch3.png

In addition, the blue section does not extend to the end of the page, but on the left side extends to the end of the page and it works.
But extends the texts with it. I want to extend the blue color only

Also the absolute feature matches the two parts of the phone and I want each part to appear separately

Thank you for your cooperation

```
<section class="connect_section connect_page scrollAnim1  start_anim active">
    <div class="connect_page_wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="connect_page_wrap_inner">
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="text_area">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text scrollAnim1 start_anim">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<main class="connect_main">
    <div class="connect">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="convertastion">
                <div class="d_test_el_wrap" style="padding-top: 80px">
                    <div class="d_test_el" contenteditable="true" style="width: 100%;min-height: 50px;">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

```
 .connect_page {
        height: auto;
        padding: 148px 0 153px;
    }
    .connect_page.connect_section {
        width: 100%
    }
    .connect_section {
        height: 238px;
        background: #272a2c;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s;
        transition: 0.5s
    }
    .connect_main .container {

        padding: 0 4.3vw

    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
        .connect_main {
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
            -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0;
            box-ordinal-group: 0;
            -webkit-order: 0;
            -moz-order: 0;
            -ms-flex-order: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, this can achieved using flexbox easily, so I suggest you to check flexbox. If you really want to go this way try adding bottom:0 to blue color part and remove the height property

Comment: How to return the part to the left i try by position: absolute;
left: 0 but not work on mobile device

Comment: the property height: auto; to extend blue on end page Is there another way

Answer (score 0):

For the sidebar to the left with full height, you should use:

```
height: 100vh
width: 200px;
position: fixed; // or absolute
top:0;
left:0;
```

Also, when you set property to `position:absolute` the height will only set for certain height mentioned; You need to set `position: fixed` to stick the sidebar.

Check live demo-> https://codepen.io/Rockingpg0/pen/NWKveNq

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand you correctly but i will try my approach. :)

I would recommend using [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). It's really easy to create a responsive pages with but [it's still not perfect](https://github.com/rachelandrew/gridbugs).

Lets have an easy example. You can run this code snippet in full page.
*Note that in media i just renamed grid areas.*

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; /* add 2 rows with auto height */
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto; /* add 2 columns with specific width */
  /* now we have two rows and two columns = 4 cells. */
  grid-template-areas: /* add name to each cell by rows to create a layout */
  "section main" 
  "section main";

  height: 100%;
  }

.connect_section {
  grid-area: section; /* this block will be in area named 'section' */
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.connect_main {
  grid-area: main; /* this block will be in area named 'main' */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .page {
    /* Just rename each cells to have different layout */
    grid-template-areas: 
    "section section"
    "main main";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <main class="connect_main">
    Main
  </main>
  
  <section class="connect_section">
    Section
  </section>
</div>
```